# Strange output of Temperature probes

Tags: temperature, probe, graph

I've got 8 ds18b20 (knock-off I assume) temperature probes monitoring the temperature in a freezer. I'm outputting the value of those probes each minute to an RRDTool graph using a Raspberry Pi.

However, occasionally I get some very strange readings and was wondering if anyone here would be able to help me figure out why.

Here's a graph for one of the eight probes (they're all pretty much the same):

[image: RRDTool Tempearture logs]

AS you can see there are 8, somewhat evenly spaced spikes in the graph.

The interesting thing is that I have 2 other probes also connected to the same 1-wire network that are just outside the freezer. They do not have any spikes at all:

[image]

The probes are hanging in free-air inside the freezer, not touching any surface.

Initially I thought that maybe there was some sort of electrical interference, maybe caused by the freezer's compressor. And this may still be the case, I'm not sure, but the fact that the 2 ambient temperature probes don't show **any** affect indicates to me that it's probably not interference. The external probes are pretty close to the freezer as well.

Also there's the fact that immediately after the spike, the temperature doesn't return to the value that it had before the spike, but seems to be cooling down and slowly leveling out as it reaches the freezer's set temperature.

I'd like to rule out electrical interference before continuing my investigation. If anyone knows whether this is possible, I'd really like to hear from you.

Some more information that may help:

It's a chest-freezer, It's not in optimal state as there's a small "leak"(?) there's water around it's base, I use old cardboard to absorb the water and it usually evaporates from the cardboard quite quickly.

**EDIT:**

So it looks like it's a daily thing. Here's some more graphs for the same sensor:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm guessing that this is just a 'feature' of the freezer, and even though it looks highly inefficient, I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: And what makes you think that these are not the real temperatures? Do you have known good probes that show different data?

Comment: Hey @PlasmaHH, thanks for the question, The only reasons is that it seems highly unlikely. I do not unfortunately have other probes, only the 10 ebay-bought ones. Would a regular (nothing-special-about-it) freezer purge cold air in this fashion? I've never heard about this sort of thing happening, surely that's a very inefficient way of doing things?

Comment: Well, you already said that it somehow leaks and generates water, so "regular" certainly does not apply here. You could try correlating things to the compressor activity, but I would recommend first checking if the probes work fine by adding an independent means of measurement. Don't you have e.g. k-type probes for your multimeter?

Comment: No I don't, just regular red-and-black positive and negative cables. But you're right, some sort of other 'independent' measuring is required. I'll have to figure out whether this is a 10PM-to-8AM regular occurrence and if so, camp out with the freezer for a while during that time and see if I can see/hear what's happening.

Comment: Are you talking about the 3 degree change every hour or so that started about 22:00 on the Sunday?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka Yes, there are 8 of them in total.

Comment: You need an independent measurement as per @PlasmaHH comment.

Comment: Once we were measuring an asic endurance at room temperature, and we saw some strange behavior, similar to what you see. Turns out that the cleaning ladies were opening the windows everyday, at the same time, causing room temperature to drop. Check that nobody is accessing the fridge :)

Comment: @VladimirCravero, Love the comment. Nope, only my wife and I in the house, the freezer is in a completely closed off room. There was no access to that part of the house at those times.

Comment: I would try to sense the current from the grid to the freezer and ouput it to the same graph. Or another signal indicating wether the motor of the freezer is operating or not.

Comment: That would be a very interesting graph indeed Uwe, I just don't have the equipment to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop in temperature during Sun AM establishes that the compressor works without producing pickup in your sensor, particularly if (as you indicate) the wires were not moved during the test, although the little glitch near the beginning of the trace may well be such pickup.

This pretty clearly indicates that the temperature swings you're seeing are real. The regularity of the swings, especially in amplitude, and to some degree in timing, also argue that the swings are real, and the freezer controller is doing something odd. The suggestion that this is a defrost cycle seems reasonable, except that I'd expect that more often, like once a day or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're probably right about the temperature drop on Sunday morning. Good spot. I'm not sure about the glitch near the beginning.  It's interesting that it is a glitch towards 0 on both graphs. Unfortunately the server running apache and _hosting_ those graphs has gone down, so I can't see what's been happening at all right now. But the Pi should still be up and running and recording all the temperature goodness. I should have some more data tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

> AS you can see there are 8, somewhat evenly spaced spikes in the graph.

could be someone opening the door, or defrosting, etc.

put a few sensors there and if they all behave the same, you can rule out a bad sensor.

Comment: There are 10 sensors on the same 1-wire network, 8 of which are in the freezer, all 8 had the same kind of spikes at the same time.

Comment: would the same 8 sensors behave comparably if they were used to measure something else? like room temperature? it seems to me that the chance of all 8 of them going bad isn't that great.

Comment: I agree, I just hope that there's no interference on them from something like the compressor. I'll try moving the sensors within the freezer to a new location within the freezer itself a bit later and see what the graphs look like tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

1. The temperature is being controlled to better than 4°C.  You haven't given any specs on what the temperature should be, so this is obviously within spec.

   Perhaps someone opened the freezer to cause the 8 events.  You haven't said anything about how controlled the conditions are for this test.

   The 8 events could be some auto-defrost cycle.

In short, you've given no reason that indicates this isn't part of normal operation, or that the result is out of spec.  There is no problem here.

Comment: (1) The temperature should be around the -21°C mark. (2) freezer remained closed. (3) I'm thinking this, however, I would like to leave this here to see if anyone else has experience anything like this (as with the comment by @Vladimir Cravero on the question above) with more solid info.